# GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl not displaying the exact list as we see in UI Windows

Tags: c#, winapi, acl

I am using the win API GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl. In a happy case when a user has all access to a folder, I am able to see the same output from the C# program like the one we get from Windows UI(Security -> Advanced -> Effective Access)

Then if I denied the user the Right permission, the Read permission in the Effective Access window is still green(see the screenshot) but I don't get the same from the API.
All other permissions are matching.

My defined ACCESS_MASK enums are as below

```
      FILE_TRAVERSE = 0x20,
      FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY = 0x1,
      FILE_READ_DATA = 0x1,
      FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES = 0x80,
      FILE_READ_EA = 0x8,
      FILE_ADD_FILE = 0x2,
      FILE_WRITE_DATA = 0x2,
      FILE_ADD_SUBDIRECTORY = 0x4,
      FILE_APPEND_DATA = 0x4,
      FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES = 0x100,
      FILE_WRITE_EA=0x10,
      FILE_DELETE_CHILD = 0x40,
      DELETE = 0x10000,
      READ_CONTROL = 0x20000,
      WRITE_DAC = 0x40000,
      WRITE_OWNER = 0x80000
```

And the Read Permission is mapped to `READ_CONTROL = 0x20000`

Any idea why would the read permission in UI would still be green or how can I map it properly in the access_mask (if I need to check other mask value) will be helpful.
I did try  `GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000` but it also didn't match in the output of the API.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the user Read permission work? And try [Authz API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-geteffectiverightsfromaclw#examples).

Comment: Is this API available in pinvoke? I can only find AuthzAccessCheck not sure if its the same

Comment: Not sure. Does the user Read permission work in fact?

Answer (score 0):

> The GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl function does not consider the
> following:
>
> - Implicitly granted access rights, such as READ_CONTROL and WRITE_DAC,
>   for the owner of an object when determining effective rights.
> - Privileges held by the trustee when determining effective access rights.
> - ...

If you are the owner of the object, you are still allowed `READ_CONTROL` even if denied in the ACL. If you are elevated administrator with the enabled privileges, you also get `READ_CONTROL`.